# Importing and exporting KML into and from DashDB for Geospatial Analysis

Tags: shapefile, kml, spatial-database, database

I am a recent convert to IBM's DashDB, and I considering proposing to use it at my work. My case would greatly be bolstered if I could show good, easy integration for geospatial analytics data, namely loading and performing SQL filtering on geodata currently in .shp or .kml formats. If it would be possible to also export the filtered data into a KML as a result that would be AMAZING.

So, to give a practical example, say I have an .SHP file with all the zipcodes in the US, I want to export that into the database, then select the shape for the 02138 zip code and send it to the query-sender in KML format.

Does anyone have experience with that?

Answer (score 1):

Directly loading KML data is not yet possible with dashDB. But you can load GML. See e.g. https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SS6NHC/com.ibm.db2.luw.spatial.topics.doc/doc/db2sb169.html%23db2sb-gen168__fun-constr-geom

If you have Esri ArcGIS tooling you can load KML data and store it into dashDB geometry columns.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use FME from Safe Software from this.

With the other proposed approaches you run the risk of losing metadata, especially with complex data types

Also, if shapes exceed the supported object size, FME easily parses them in to multiple objects.

Last, the shapefile importer for dashDB does not support all valid shapefile formats.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily load Shapefiles into dashDB using the user interface. Instructions here: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.doc/learn_how/loaddata_gsdata.html